# C#.net : Accidental Double Click on a button shows 2 different forms

Tags: c#, winforms

so here's my code:

```
   private void loginbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      LogIn();
   }
    private void LogIn()
    {
        //some code to validate users
        //if user and password is in db, show Form2 and record login event to Audit Trail table
    }
```

I never knew this problem is possible to happen until i accidentally pressed enter twice,because i set `loginbtn` as `AcceptButton` for `Form1` and suddenly, two `Form2`'s popped up on my screen, and so I restarted my program and tried to double click the `loginbtn` to check the problem, and yes, two `Form2`'s popped up again on my screen. This only happens on accidental double clicks and not when i click the button once or press the enter button once at the `Form1`.
Someone please tell me how to prevent it from running the action twice? how do i fix it? 
Thank you so much.

Comment: Disable the button before showing the form? Show the form modally?

Comment: This is a common question, please search first before asking something that is likely to have been solved before. Would recommend [ask] if you are new to the site which has some helpful pointers for interacting on [so].

Comment: Now that you've given the link to the post, it did answer my question.
i was not able to search for it because i thought the problem was with the button. 
but thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution is to declare a boolean variable, `IsShowing`, which is `true` when `Form2` is showing and `false` when it is not. Then you can write:

```
private void loginbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (!IsShowing) 
     LogIn();
}
```

Another solution I can think of is to set `Form2` as modal. Doing like this, the second instance won't appear anymore.

A third solution would be disabling the button after `Form2` is showing.

Comment: There is an already an [excellent solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14920510/692942) that doesn't require introducing extra variables.

Comment: still thank you for taking your time to answer my question.